# Dynamically change Django models attributes

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am trying to create fixtures for a django app using [factory_boy](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy) for a an app that has circular dependencies [factory_boy: circular dependencies](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/subfactory.html#circular-dependencies).

models:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

class B(models.Model):
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=False)
```

factory:

```
# in AFactory
b = SubFactory(BFactory)
# in BFactory
c = SubFactory(CFactory)
# in CFactory
a = CircularSubFactory('a_factory', 'AFactory', b__c__a=None)
```

When running my factory_boy script using these factories, I am faced with a `ValueError: Cannot assign None: "C.a" does not allow null values` error, which is normal as `C.a` has `null=False` set.

Is it possible to load `C`, alter `C.a` to set `null=True` and then run my factory_boy script ?

A few points :

- I know that would be ugly but it seems like I have no other choice. It will only used internally to create fixtures though.
- I cannot change my models as it is an already running app with these class being a part of the core.

Comment: How do you expect your fixtures to work if they are outputting a NULL for that C.a relationship? They won't import.

Comment: So the column in database does not allow null and you want to force it to allow it without altering it? Obviously that's not possible. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @freakish: I will be running the factory_boy script inside a custom management command that will alter the table (yes, really...).

Comment: @Jordan I don't know if it is possible to get a reference of the `A` object. I've asked factory_boy's creator how I should handle this on IRC and am awaiting his answer.